# Will Studying Mathematical Analysis and Single Variable Calculus Simultaneously create confusion?

Tags: calculus, analysis

I have started studying Mathematics from the undergraduate level up, but I am aware I am studying Analysis from Apostols book which deals with Very rigorous mathematics it seems also including metric spaces.

For Calculus I am studying from Ron larsons Book Calculus and would it create confusion to encounter definitions on a more simple level in calculus whilst more advanced in mathematical analysis.

**For example I came across this definition for Defining a Continuous Function in my Calculus Book under the Topics Limit:**

[image]

**This is the definition from the MAthematical Analysis book by Apostol , although not having yet reached this topic yet :** [image]

Comment: As Apostol says, his definition is just an extension of the single-variable definition. If you are ready to grapple with that definition then I don’t see the harm in having the more elementary definition at hand for comparison. If you’re not ready for analysis then doing it alone won’t make you ready.

Comment: Thank you Sir. I often have a  neurotic obsession over these things . I will just go through it and just try and attempt to have a panaramic understanding of the material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Yes", but it depends on your own mathematical sophistication.  The basics of analysis and the basics of calculus are neither incompatible nor mutually confusing.  However, there is a tendency in many introductory calculus books to skirt around or simplify some of the rigour that you will find in your analysis text.  That being said, it is not super relevant.  Many students study, for example, linear algebra and calculus in their first terms of university without much concern for confusion.  The two subjects are essentially treated as different parts of a mathematical education.

The issue you may see with analysis and calculus together is that there are some very formal proofs in analysis (and calculus, but rarely in intro texts) that make it hard to see the forest for the trees.  At the end of the day, introductory calculus is about learning the foundations for the rules of differentiation and integration and how to apply those rules to novel problems.  Analysis is a deep dive into why those rules are even something we are allowed to state and rely upon.  As a result knowing, say, Lipschitz continuity isn't going to make it any easy to differentiate $\cos(ln(x+3)))$.  However, knowing about the depth will make it a lot more fun.

There is also the issue that analysis is usually an upper-year course compared to single variable calculus.  As a result, the book you will find for analysis may just assume you've taken a bunch more courses on proof, logic, and general mathematics than you have, and you may go slow.

Ultimately, I don't think you will find yourself at a disadvantage as long as you give appropriate time and effort to both subjects.  However, you'll find it easier to wait on analysis.

Comment: Thank you Both.